# Pantone appearance on screen in PS6

Tags: pantone

According to the company's book of standards, the color we use is Pantone 534 U. When I select it in my PS6, it appears absolutely different, lighter, more gray. Since I am using the color for online posts, I am not so much worried about printing it, but how to achieve the right color on my posts.
Thank you in advance for help.

BTW, I am absolutely new to editing in PS, so please write your response for dummies. Thanks  :)

Comment: When you say PS6, are you referring to Photoshop CS 6? or Print Shop 6?

Answer (score 1):

See if the coated version of 534 is closer to what you want.

**Context:** Pantone colours are for printing inks or fabric colours. On screen colours are made by light, not ink, so they always vary a bit.

There's more variation with 534u because the 'U' stands for uncoated, as in uncoated paper (for example, in a newspaper). They absorb more ink than coated paper so the ink values are different to (try to) take account of that.

Usually a guide will specify just the Pantone number (if it includes a letter, it's usually 'c'). Most would also give equivalents for CMYK and screen/web colours. I've never seen a guide that specified **only** a 'u' colour and nothing else. Might be worth another look to check there aren't more colour values listed elsewhere in the book or an appendix?

Comment: Just to take on some extra information: I checked my Pantone formula guides and found that 534 U is pretty close to what's given in the Photoshop CC15 color library. In my formula guides, 534 C is a much deeper blue than the U counterpart.

Comment: But yeah, a decent branding/design guideline should have specific RGB values in addition to Pantone. Pantone is for print; I wouldn't be comfortable using Photoshop or Illustrator's baked in conversion for web work. If RGB values aren't specified in the standards, I'd just ask for clarification.